# Что я не дописываю в файле .env при подключении sqlsrv?

Tags: php, sql

хочу подключить БД с помощью sqlsrv, я понимаю что это прописывается в файле .env, но у меня возникает такая ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот файл database.php

```
        'sqlsrv' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
    ],
```

вот файл .env

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=1433
DB_DATABASE=forge
DB_USERNAME=forge
DB_PASSWORD=
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я делаю не так? Заранее спасибо

Comment: Что сказано в ошибке? Переведите для нас и осмыслите сами.

Comment: обычно для консоли используется отдельный конфиг пхп. вероятно там драйвер sqlsrv не включен